# Issue with Variations on SharePoint 2019

Tags: error, variations, 2019, multilingual

I have a site with 12 pages inside the /Pages document library and also 5 sub-sites and 7 lists.

I want to create variations for this site in English and French (French package language already installed).

But the issue is, after I create the labels, and then click on Create Hierarchy.
This is the error occurring:

> The Variations Create Hierarchies job failed with the following error message:
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The variations are created but the pages, lists and sites are not propagated.
Also, there is no routing managed even if the Variation Root page exists.

I deleted the labels and the variations sites, and then re-do the operation but the error is still occurring.

Please help.

here is the error from the ULS log

```
Being disposed SPCPUCycleData of MonitoredScope (Name=SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset, ScopeId=278944644334032, ThreadId=95, CorrelationId=71cbf99e-ac4e-c0de-d5c9-4f5f64b6065e) is not active on this thread (threadId:14964) because monitored scope or CPUCycleDate is disposed out of order. StackTrace:  
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPCPUCycleData.Deactivate()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPCPUCycleData.Dispose(Boolean checkThreadId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPMonitoredScope.OnDisposing()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPMonitoredScope.Dispose(Boolean disposing)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, ISPFileStreamReader spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateWeb(String bstrUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, Boolean bCreateUniqueWeb, Guid& pguidAppInstanceId, String bstrAppWebDomainId, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid& pgWebId, Guid& pgRootFolderId, Boolean bCreateSystemCatalogs)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateWeb(String bstrUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, Boolean bCreateUniqueWeb, Guid& pguidAppInstanceId, String bstrAppWebDomainId, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid& pgWebId, Guid& pgRootFolderId, Boolean bCreateSystemCatalogs)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateWeb(String bstrUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, Boolean bCreateUniqueWeb, Guid& pguidAppInstanceId, String bstrAppWebDomainId, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid& pgWebId, Guid& pgRootFolderId, Boolean bCreateSystemCatalogs)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.CreateWeb(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean bCreateUniqueSubweb, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid appInstanceId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.SPWebCollectionProvider.CreateWeb(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean bCreateUniqueSubweb, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid appInstanceId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.Add(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean useUniquePermissions, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid appInstanceId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.Add(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean useUniquePermissions, Boolean bConvertIfThere)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWebCollection.addPublishingWeb(String newAreaUrl, String newAreaTitle, UInt32 languageId, String webTemplateName)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CreateVariationHierarchiesJobDefinition.CreateVariationSourceTopWeb(SPWeb rootWeb, PublishingWeb varRootArea, VariationLabel sourceLabel, CachedVariationSettings variationSettings, IVariationsLog lroLogger, List`1 errors, Boolean& succeeded)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CreateVariationHierarchiesJobDefinition.InitializeVariations(SPSite rootSite, SPWeb rootWeb, PublishingWeb varRootArea, CachedVariationSettings& variationSettings, VariationLabel sourceLabel, IVariationsLog lroLogger, List`1 errors, Boolean& succeeded)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CreateVariationHierarchiesJobDefinition.PerformVariationsSpawn(SPWorkItem workItem, SPWeb currentWeb, CachedVariationSettings variationSettings)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.VariationsSpawnJobDefinitionBase.ProcessWorkItemCore(SPWorkItem workItem, WorkItemTimerJobState timerJobState)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.TimerJobUtility.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ProcessWorkItem>b__0()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.MonitoredScopeWrapper.RunWithMonitoredScope(Action code)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.TimerJobUtility.ProcessWorkItem(SPWorkItemCollection workItems, SPWorkItem wi, WorkItemTimerJobState timerJobState, ProcessWorkItemWithState processor, ProcessWorkItemError errorProcessor)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.TimerJobUtility.ProcessWorkItem(SPWorkItemCollection workItems, SPWorkItem wi, WorkItemTimerJobState timerJobState, ProcessWorkItemWithState processor)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.VariationsSpawnJobDefinitionBase.ProcessWorkItem(SPContentDatabase contentDatabase, SPWorkItemCollection workItems, SPWorkItem workItem, SPJobState jobState)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWorkItemJobDefinition.ProcessWorkItems(SPContentDatabase contentDatabase, SPWorkItemCollection workItems, SPJobState jobState)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWorkItemJobDefinition.HandleOneContentDatabase(SPContentDatabase db, SPJobState jobState)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWorkItemJobDefinition.Execute(SPJobState jobState)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.VariationsSpawnJobDefinitionBase.Execute(SPJobState jobState)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvoke.Invoke(TimerJobExecuteData& data, Int32& result)
```

Comment: Are you able to check ULS logger to get some more information about the issue? If not, please, set log level to verbose and try creating the variation sites. Once the error appear, set log level to the default value to not keep creating large log files. Ask IT team for log files

Comment: Hi, i just edited my question, please see above

Comment: It seems that fails when creating the subsiste. Did you check if there is a subsiste with the same name/url you are trying to create? Is there any more useful information in ULS messages in preview or post entries?

Comment: Looks like this issue happens only on this web application. i created another web app on the same farm, it worked fine.

Comment: Variations must be created on the root site. Is that your case? I can't figure out what else could happen without log information, please, share more ULS information in order to understand what's the issue.